# How to add a month to a date accounting for a leap year and different number of days in Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add exactly one month to a date using Google script. This is what I have so far, which works fine up to a point;

```
var everyNth  = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();               // cell which contains the date
                everyNth.setMonth(everyNth.getMonth() + 1);   // adds 1 month to the date
```

If date value is 5/25/2020 the above returns 6/25/2020 which is as intended
If date value is 2/29/2020 the above returns 3/29/2020 which is NOT as intended

I need it to return 3/31/2020, which is exactly one month after, same if the month has 30 or 31 days.

Comment: Your question is about as clear as mud.  Please provide some examples of desired output for a given input.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you mean.  If you have a date like mm/dd/yyyy which month do you want to add to it the current month or the next month.

Comment: Accepted the answer. That was what I was trying to achieve. As for the question, I agree, it could have been clearer. Something I hope to improve on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Number of Days in the next month**

This function adds the number of days in the next month to the dates in column A and puts the resulting date in column B

I have this data in column one:

```
1/25/2020
2/25/2020
3/25/2020
4/25/2020
5/25/2020
6/25/2020
7/25/2020
8/25/2020
9/25/2020
10/25/2020
11/25/2020
12/25/2020
```

If I run this function using the next month for each date in column one:

```
function dateplay() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  const output=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  output.forEach(function(e,i){
    let dt=new Date(data[i][0]);    
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+daysInNextMonth(dt.getMonth()+1));
    e[0]=dt;
  });
  sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1).setValues(output);
}

function daysInNextMonth(m=0) {
  return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),m+1,0).getDate();
}
```

Then I get this output in column two that adds the numbers of days in the next month to the first column entrees:(I provided both columns this time)

```
1/25/2020,2/23/2020
2/25/2020,3/27/2020
3/25/2020,4/24/2020
4/25/2020,5/26/2020
5/25/2020,6/24/2020
6/25/2020,7/26/2020
7/25/2020,8/25/2020
8/25/2020,9/24/2020
9/25/2020,10/26/2020
10/25/2020,11/24/2020
11/25/2020,12/26/2020
12/25/2020,1/25/2021
```

Data is csv format.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would add a day to the date. I need the date to be the last day of the month. I tried it out and it gave me 3/30/2020, not 3/31/2020. This would also not work if the month had 30 or 31 days.

Comment: You asked how to add a month and some days to a date.  That is an example of what you asked for. If you wish to ask for something else then ask another question and be clear about what you want.  Try to do it yourself first.

Comment: I asked to add a month to a date. If you add a month to a date, for example, if you add a month to 3/31/2020 you should get 4/30/2020 and if you add a month to that new date you should get 5/31/2020. I thought that was clear from how I framed the question. If it is not then, this is what I need. Your answer does make that possible but the months need to be hard-coded. I am looking for a function that takes into account the day difference between the months and the leap year as well.

Comment: The example now provides the end of month

Comment: This still skips the months, if I set 3/31/2020 as date and run it, it gives me 5/31/2020, it skips April which has 30 days. Either I am doing something wrong or this just plainly escapes me.

Comment: What I want is to add a one month period to any date which correctly accounts for the day difference in months if a date falls on the last day of the month.

Comment: @SystemWorks You keep mentioning: *"What I want is to add a one month period..."* But a one month period can be 30 days OR 31 days OR 29 days OR 28 days OR varies 31-28 days. I believe you need to clarify that.

Comment: @marikamitsos Yes, that is exactly what I want. Regardless of how many days in the month there are if the date finishes on the last day of the month then the next date should also be on the last day of the next month.